# Convert a Bitmap to a 1bit Monochrome/Black and white Bitmap VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a BMP file.. a basic barcode image.. When I go to save it Bitmap.save(File) it saves the BMP file all fine, but when I open it in photoshop its a indexed or RGB color bmp files.

I need the file to be a 1bit black and white bmp file. Its just a barcode...

I have been googling for hours, and I am unable to convert the c# examples (often uses Unsafe code) and all other examples are also just creating what photoshop sees as a RGB image.

I need the file to be 1bit bmp as its loaded onto a ePaper device (like a kindle reader) and the device supplier has provided sample bitmaps that when loaded into photoshop as a mode Bitmap... not RGB or indexed.

Any tips on how to get the file saved correctly ?

HPD

Here is the code i was working with...

```
    Dim original = New Bitmap("c:\temp\24.bmp")
    Dim Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height)
    Dim bmp1bpp = original.Clone(Rectangle, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)
    bmp1bpp.Save("c:\temp\24bit1.bmp")
```

Comment: Can you post your code? The Bitmap class supports the format `Format1bppIndexed` which should be what you need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the code i was working with...
        Dim original = New Bitmap("c:\temp\24.bmp")
        Dim Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height)
        Dim bmp1bpp = original.Clone(Rectangle, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)
        bmp1bpp.Save("c:\temp\24bit1.bmp")

Answer (score -1):

here is sample conversion code in c#:

```
private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{
    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

    foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs) {
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid) {
            return codec;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = new Bitmap(@"d:\test.bmp");
    var output = input.Clone(
        new Rectangle(0, 0, input.Width, input.Height),
        PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

    var encoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Bmp);
    var param = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 1L);
    var paramss = new EncoderParameters(1);
    paramss.Param[0] = param;

    output.Save(@"d:\test_out.bmp", encoder, paramss);
}
```

and it produces bitmap mode bmp

here is conversion to vb:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Module Module1
    Function GetEncoder(ByVal format As ImageFormat) As ImageCodecInfo
        Dim codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()

        For Each codec As ImageCodecInfo In codecs
            If codec.FormatID = format.Guid Then
                Return codec
            End If
        Next

        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim input = New Bitmap("d:\test.bmp")
        Dim output = input.Clone(
            New Rectangle(0, 0, input.Width, input.Height),
            PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)

        Dim encoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Bmp)
        Dim param = New EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ColorDepth, 1L)
        Dim paramss = New EncoderParameters(1)
        paramss.Param(0) = param

        output.Save("d:\test_out.bmp", encoder, paramss)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: HI, 

Thanks for this.. I have used a convertor (telerik) to convert this to vb code.. but I get one error... the Encoder.ColorDepth statement.. I get back ColorDepth is not a member of ImageCodeInfo.

I have found some other examples for this method, but all are still failing me.. they actually end up creating a 76kb file from the original that was only 4kb size...

Comment: @HPD71 ImageCodeInfo has no colordepth, Encoder - has, `System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ColorDepth`